# Silverlight DataGrid duplicate error messages for objects using both DataAnnotations and INotifyDataErrorInfo

Tags: c#, silverlight, validation, datagrid

My Entity objects use DataAnnotations attributes for validation, but for validation to work with all Silverlight controls and not only DataGrid, I also implemented INotifyDataErrorInfo. But this produces duplicate validation errors text in DataGrid (It shows error from both DataAnnotations and INotifyDataErrorInfo). How can I fix this?

My ModelBase class: http://pastebin.com/SewggVUc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I misunderstood what INotidyDataErrorInfo.GetErrors(string property) should return when null or empty property is provided, I thought that it should return all properties errors, but no it should return class top level errors, I was rising ErrorsChanged event with both property and null argument supplied, so it was showing duplicate messages, one for property, one for class level, and in my case they were the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [a link to a blog post](http://outcoldman.ru/en/blog/show/260) that can help you.

Author describes how to combine INotifyDataErrorInfo and DataAnnotations at the end of the post.

If nothing changes - add code of the Entity class to your question.

Comment: yeah I seen this post. My base ModelView class is pretty much standard I think, I have added link below the question.